# How to do jquery validation on something that is equal to zero, but not when its null/empty

Tags: jquery, validation, null, numbers, zero

So I want to validate a textbox that I have, the user can leave this box blank which is fine.  However if they enter the number 0 in it, I want an error message to appear.  However if it say is it null, it validates as an error when it is empty as well. 
I have done is it equal to "0" in quotes, however if they put more than one 0 it accepts it.  So what can I do to validate to check if it is 0, but not null. 
I tried loads, this is my latest try, but nothing works

```
    if (this.value == 0 && this.value != null){
    }
```

Thanks

What "**Rhumborl**" said works great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (parseFloat(this.value) === 0) {
}
```

should work for decimals. you shouldn't need parseInt as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could to something like:

```
if (parseInt(this.value, 10) === 0) {
}
```

in case of `null` or empty string it would return `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks, this does work for whole numbers.  Is there possible a way to do it for decimals like  .0 or .00

Comment: Ok, not sure if its the right way to do it, but what I have works, I'll post it above